# Use parquet file with special characters in column names in PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

**MAIN GOAL**
Show or select columns from the Spark dataframe read from the parquet file.
All the solutions mentioned in the forum are not successfull in our case.

**PROBLEM**
The issue happens when the parquet file is read and queried with SPARK and is due to the presence of special characters  `,;{}()\n\t=` within column names. The problem was reproduced with a simple parquet files with two columns and five rows. The names of the columns are:

- `SpeedReference_Final_01 (RifVel_G0)`
- `SpeedReference_Final_02 (RifVel_G1)`

The error arised is:
`Attribute name "SpeedReference_Final_01 (RifVel_G0)" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.`

We are using **PySpark** in Python language and the experimented solutions can be categorized as it follows:

1. **Solutions based on column rename** - [`spark.read.parquet` + rename of the obtained dataframe]
   Several solutions have been experimented:

   - `withColumnRenamed` (Issue N.2 within the script)
   - `toDF` (Issue N.3)
   - `alias` (Issue N.5)

   None of them is working in our case.
2. **Read the parquet file into a Pandas dataframe and then create a new one from it** - [`pd.read.parquet` + `spark.createDataFrame`]
   This solution is working with a small parquet file (Issue N.0 i.e. WORKAROUND within the script): the created spark dataframe can be successfully queried even if it has column names containing special characters. **Unfortunately it is unpracticable with our big parquet files** (600000 rows x 1000 columns for each parquet), since creating the spark dataframe is interminable.
3. **An attempt to read the parquet file into a Spark dataframe and create a new Spark dataframe with its `rdd` and a renamed schema** is not practicable since the extraction of the `rdd` from the Spark dataframe arises the same error (Issue N.4).
4. **Read the parquet file with a prefixed schema** (that avoids the special characters) - [`spark.read.schema(...).parquet`]
   The solution is not working, since data related to critical columns become null/None as expected since the renamed columns are not present within the original file.

The mentioned solutions are summarized in the python code below and have been experimented with the [Example parquet file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jp9zqwahtjabw77/Simple.parquet?dl=0).

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

import pandas as pd

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Select file
filename = 'D:/Simple.parquet'

issue_num = 0 # Workaround to issues (Equivalent to no issue)
#issue_num = 1 # Issue 1 - Unable to show dataframe or select column with name containing invalid character(s)
#issue_num = 2 # Issue 2 - Unable to show dataframe or select column after rename (using withColumnRenamed)
#issue_num = 3 # Issue 3 - Unable to show dataframe or select column after rename (using toDF)
#issue_num = 4 # Issue 4 - Unable to extract rdd from renamed dataframe 
#issue_num = 5 # Issue 5 - Unable to select column with alias

if issue_num == 0:

    ################################################################################################
    # WORKAROUND - Create Spark data frame from Pandas dataframe
    df_pd = pd.read_parquet(filename)
    DF = spark.createDataFrame(df_pd)
    print('WORKAROUND')
    DF.show()
    # +-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
    # |SpeedReference_Final_01 (RifVel_G0)|SpeedReference_Final_02 (RifVel_G1)|
    # +-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
    # |                  553.5228271484375|                     720.3720703125|
    # |                  553.5228271484375|                     720.3720703125|
    # |                  553.5228271484375|                     720.3720703125|
    # |                  553.5228271484375|                     720.3720703125|
    # |                  553.5228271484375|                     720.3720703125|
    # +-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+

    ################################################################################################
    # Correct management of columns with  invalid characters when using spark.createDataFrame
    # spark.createDataFrame: Create a dataframe with two columns with  invalid characters - OK
    # DFCREATED
    schema = StructType(
        [
            StructField("SpeedReference_Final_01 (RifVel_G0)", FloatType(), nullable=True),
            StructField("SpeedReference_Final_02 (RifVel_G1)", FloatType(), nullable=True)
        ]
    )

    row_in = [(553.523,720.372), (553.523,720.372), (553.523,720.372), (553.523,720.372), (553.523,720.372)]

    rdd=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(row_in)
    DFCREATED = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
    DFCREATED.show()
    # +-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
    # |SpeedReference_Final_01 (RifVel_G0)|SpeedReference_Final_02 (RifVel_G1)|
    # +-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
    # |                            553.523|                            720.372|
    # |                            553.523|                            720.372|
    # |                            553.523|                            720.372|
    # |                            553.523|                            720.372|
    # |                            553.523|                            720.372|
    # +-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
    DF_SEL_VAR_CREATED = DFCREATED.select(DFCREATED.columns[0]).take(2)
    for el in DF_SEL_VAR_CREATED:
        print(el)
    #Row(SpeedReference_Final_01 (RifVel_G0)=553.5230102539062)
    #Row(SpeedReference_Final_01 (RifVel_G0)=553.5230102539062)
    
else:
    # spark.read: read file into dataframe - OK
    DF = spark.read.parquet(filename)
    print('ORIGINAL SCHEMA')
    DF.printSchema()
    # root
    #  |-- SpeedReference_Final_01 (RifVel_G0): float (nullable = true)
    #  |-- SpeedReference_Final_02 (RifVel_G1): float (nullable = true)
    
    if issue_num == 1:
        ###############################################################################################    
        # Issue 1 - Unable to show dataframe or select column with name containing invalid character(s)
        DF.show()
        # DF.select(DF.columns[0]).show()
        # DF_SEL_VAR = DF.select(DF.columns[0]).take(3)
        #ECC: Attribute name "SpeedReference_Final_01 (RifVel_G0)" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.
        # on all 3 previous statements

    elif issue_num == 2:
        ###############################################################################################    
        # Issue 2 - Unable to show dataframe or select column after rename (using withColumnRenamed)
        DFRENAMED = DF.withColumnRenamed('SpeedReference_Final_01 (RifVel_G0)','RifVelG0').withColumnRenamed('SpeedReference_Final_02 (RifVel_G1)','RifVelG1')
       
        print('RENAMED SCHEMA')
        DFRENAMED.printSchema()
        # root
        #  |-- RifVelG0: float (nullable = true)
        #  |-- RifVelG1: float (nullable = true)

        DFRENAMED.show()
        # DF_SEL_VAR_RENAMED = DFRENAMED.select(DFRENAMED.RifVelG0).take(2)
        #ECC: Attribute name "SpeedReference_Final_01 (RifVel_G0)" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.
        # on all 2 previous statements

    elif issue_num == 3:
        ###############################################################################################    
        # Issue 3 - Unable to show dataframe or select column after rename (using to_DF)
        DFRENAMED = DF.toDF('RifVelG0', 'RifVelG1')
    
        print('RENAMED SCHEMA')
        DFRENAMED.printSchema()
        # root
        #  |-- RifVelG0: float (nullable = true)
        #  |-- RifVelG1: float (nullable = true)

        DFRENAMED.show()
        # DF_SEL_VAR_RENAMED = DFRENAMED.select(DFRENAMED.RifVelG0).take(2)
        #ECC: Attribute name "SpeedReference_Final_01 (RifVel_G0)" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.
        # on all 2 previous statements

    elif issue_num == 4:
        ###############################################################################################    
        # Issue 4 - Unable to extract rdd from renamed dataframe 
        DFRENAMED = DF.withColumnRenamed('SpeedReference_Final_01 (RifVel_G0)','RifVelG0').withColumnRenamed('SpeedReference_Final_02 (RifVel_G1)','RifVelG1')
        DFRENAMED_rdd = DFRENAMED.rdd
        #ECC: Attribute name "SpeedReference_Final_01 (RifVel_G0)" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.

    elif issue_num == 5:
        ###############################################################################################    
        # Issue 5 - Unable to select column with alias
        DF_SEL_VAR = DF.select(col(DF.columns[0]).alias('RifVelG0')).take(3)
        #ECC: Attribute name "SpeedReference_Final_01 (RifVel_G0)" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.
```

Have you any idea on how we can solve the problem?

Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
import re
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

def remove_special_characters(string: str):
    return re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "", string)

DFCREATED = DFCREATED.select(
    [
        f.col(column).alias(remove_special_characters(column))
        for column in DFCREATED.columns
    ]
)
```

also I think you can use this function to remove other things like space.